# Can't get Canvas/CanvasLayer working in Playn

Tags: java, canvas, playn

Like the title says, I can't get Canvas/CanvasLayer working in PlayN. My sample code couldn't be simpler. The ImageLayer and default background loads fine (that code is commented out here), but the canvas is practically invisible always.

```
public void init() {
    // create and add background image layer
    //Image bgImage = assetManager().getImage("images/bg.png");
    //ImageLayer bgLayer = graphics().createImageLayer(bgImage);
    //graphics().rootLayer().add(bgLayer);      
    graphics().setSize(500, 400);

    CanvasLayer testLayer = graphics().createCanvasLayer(200,200);
    Canvas testCanvas = testLayer.canvas();

    graphics().rootLayer().add(testLayer);
    //testCanvas.clear();

    testCanvas.setStrokeColor(0x000000);
    testCanvas.setStrokeWidth(2);
    testCanvas.setFillColor(0xff0000);
    testCanvas.drawText("hello", 50, 50);
    testCanvas.drawLine(0, 0, 300,300);
    testCanvas.strokeRect(1, 1, 46, 46);

    //I even tried adding this.
    testLayer.setAlpha(1);
    testLayer.setVisible(true);
    testLayer.setScale(1);
}
```

I'm using PlayN 1.0.3 with Maven. Note this is for the pure java compilation.

TIA Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your color codes are wrong, you must specify alpha as well

`0x000000` actually means 00 alpha, 00 red, 00 gren

try this instead:

`testCanvas.setStrokeColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));`

or if you want 50% transparency:

`testCanvas.setStrokeColor(Color.argb(0x80, 0, 0, 0));`

you might also want to add a background as well, **before** you add your CanvasLayer:

```
    SurfaceLayer bgLayer = graphics().createSurfaceLayer(500, 400);
    bgLayer.surface().setFillColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0));
    bgLayer.surface().fillRect(0, 0, bgLayer.surface().width(),
            bgLayer.surface().height());
    graphics().rootLayer().add(bgLayer);
```

Comment: Thanx! I eyeballed the code from the demo and was not used to the 0xXXX notation for colour, expecting a more 'new Color()' class orientated notation, being java and all. Obviously I can see the benefits to primitives for efficiency when porting to GWT/javascript etc. 

Thanx for pointing out the two digits I was missing, and saving me a load of time! One always thinks the cause is more complicated than it is :-)